# How to read lines from stdin whenever available (block otherwise)?

Tags: perl, unix, named-pipes

In the code below `p00` is a named pipe, created with `mkfifo p00`.

In console 1, I ran:

```
% perl -ne 'print "PERL: $_"' < p00
```

Then, while the above blocked (as expected), in console 2 I ran

```
% seq 3 > p00
```

As a result, the following appeared in console 1:

```
PERL: 1
PERL: 2
PERL: 3
%
```

This was *almost* the result I had hoped to achieve, except for the fact that the `perl` script terminated after printing the third line.

> I want the script to continue echoing lines (prefixed by "PERL: ") *as soon as* they become available, and **block** otherwise.

The following variant of the one-liner above superficially *resembles* the desired behavior:

```
perl -e 'while ( 1 ) { print "PERL: $_" while <>; sleep 1 }' < p00
```

...but it's not the real deal, because it does not block while waiting for input, nor it echoes its input as soon as it is available.

NOTES:

1. the motivation behind this question is education (mine, that is) and nothing more; I'm not trying to solve any practical problem; I'm just trying to learn more perl (and unix).
2. I wasn't sure if this question was more suited for unix.se.com; I'm more than happy to re-post it there if it is; just let me know.

Comment: It is the way `fifo` behaves: once the writer closes it the reader gets `EOF`. The reader probably has to re-open `fifo` but it can't be done with shell redirection.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Your comment made me realize that all I had to do was to get rid of the `sleep 1`! Then the second version I posted does exactly what I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Maxim Yegorushkin's comment I realized that all I had to do was get rid of the `sleep 1` in the second version.  I.e., this does exactly what I want:

```
perl -e 'while ( 1 ) { print "PERL: $_" while <> }' < p00
```

As Maxim wrote, the inner loop terminates upon receiving the `EOF`; then the outer loop returns the script to a blocking state, waiting for input...  Doh!

Comment: It's interesting; suppose `p00` is a file instead of a FIFO.  Then your revised script will read extra lines as they're added to the file (either `>>` to append, or rewrite the file and add more lines than there were before).  So, Perl is resetting the EOF indicator on the input stream (standard input) before the new attempt to read.